# Placing Points within Polygon?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I am looking to plot the ideal placement of police vehicles within a specific precinct (polygon). Rather than placing them myself, calculating a buffer of travel time (e.g. within 3 minutes), and using trial and error I'd like for the best placement to be determined pragmatically. By the ideal placement I mean the positions of the points (cars) that covers the highest percentage of the roads within the polygon.

Is there a way to accomplish this using Python/model builder?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are looking for a solution in ESRI environment.That being the case customizing ESRI sample on [drive time polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00570000009p000000)  or another JS [sample](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/fl_selection/) could help you.
Firstly you can find the drive time polygons for a given time period using 
centroid or some random locations within inner buffer of the precinct polygon.An intersection test of the resulting polygon with the roads can help you in determining the location automatically.